# Highcharts Stock y-axis settings

Tags: highcharts

Can some help set-up the y-axis on my candlestick chart? I want the y-axis to have 0.25 tick interval with the y-axis' min/max being lowest/highest points for the data set.

I've been trying combinations of  `tickInterval`, `minTickInterval`, `minorTickInterval`, and `getExtremesFromAll` to no luck.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            series: [{
                name: 'ES   ',
                type: 'candlestick',
                data: this.csvData
            }],
            xAxis: {
                units: [[
                    'minute',
                    [1]
                ]]
            },
            yAxis: {
                // tickInterval: 0.25,
                // minTickInterval: 0.25,
                // minorTickInterval: 0.25
            },
        });
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the official examples site?  Do any of them do roughly what you want?

Comment: Paste your code here or recreate the problem on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cypk9kya/

Comment: yeah, I reviewed the official docs and I haven't been able to figure out how to set up the chart how I want it to look. I've been able to get the yAxis to increment by 0.25 but its increment every 0.25.

Comment: Can you refer to my fiddle? How the chart should look like? You can also try to set the ticks with tickPositions/tickPositioner http://jsfiddle.net/cypk9kya/1/